# How can we get results from two different procedures in snowflake using python exported in two different sheets?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, google-sheets, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I used the following command to export the result derived from procedure in snowflake using python:

```
# executecriptfromfile function call1
executecriptfromfile('Warehouse.sql')
print('Warehouse activated')
# executecriptfromfile function call2
executecriptfromfile('ProcedureCall.sql')
print('Procedure executed')
dataframe = pd.read_sql("""
               SELECT *
               FROM DATAWAHOUSE.SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME
               """, con)
dataframe.to_excel(r'D:CompletePath/Report.xlsx', index=False)
```

(Here, con is the datawarehouse connection and the Warehouse.sql is the warehouse activation file and ProcedureCall.sql is the file where the call statement of the procedure is kept)
This is working perfectly fine and the result is dumped in the excel file in the mentioned path.

However, I want to now use the results obtained from two different procedures (ProcedureCall1.sql and ProcedureCall2.sql) and export them in excel file in two different sheets.
How can I get it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The doc says:

If you wish to write to more than one sheet in the workbook, it is necessary to specify an ExcelWriter object:

```
df1 = pd.read_sql( ..... )    
df2 = pd.read_sql( ..... )
with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:  
    df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet_name_1')
    df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet_name_2')
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html